# IQueryable & select new

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Here is a function that returns an `IQueryable` of `Note` objects.

```
private IQueryable<Note> SqlGetNotes()
{
    //only notes belonging to memoboard
    var notes = from n in _db.Notes select n;
    return notes;
}
```

In the below code, I am calling the above function and creating my own objects with just list of note ids.

```
var noteItems = (from n in SqlGetNotes()
                 select new
                 {
                     Id = n.NoteId,
                 }).ToList();
```

My question is, will the above query first load all the columns of the `Note` object, or just the `NoteId` column?

I have a doubt because in `SqlGetNotes` I am using '`select n`' and then I use '`select new`'.

I want to write the `IQueryable` such a way that only the `Id` column is read from the database.

Comment: `SqlGetNotes` can be implemented as just `return _db.Notes;`  The `select` you have there does literally nothing.

Comment: I just simplified it for this example. In actual scenario I have a where clause too. I intentionally wanted to show select n.

Comment: It just makes a Query and doesn't fetch data from database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first query, is *just* a query, it hasn't returned anything yet. You need to iterate your query to get the results, using `ToList`, `ToArray` etc.

You iterated your query in second code snippet, where you actually requested the field `NoteId` and iterated your query using `ToList`.

Thus, your SQL query generated would only select `NoteId` and not all the columns. You can use a SQL profiler to  see the actual generated query from LINQ expression.

Answer (score 0):

Have you observed the profiler behavior by putting breakpoints before and after calling `.ToList()`?

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> The `IQueryable` interface inherits the `IEnumerable` interface so that if it represents a query, the results of that query can be enumerated. Enumeration causes the expression tree associated with an `IQueryable` object to be executed. The definition of "executing an expression tree" is specific to a query provider. For example, it may involve translating the expression tree to an appropriate query language for the underlying data source.

This would mean that as long as I have an `IQueryable` object, I can do other things with it like doing a `.Select()` for projection (like what you are doing with `select new`) or `.Where()` to apply filtering, if needed, without executing the backend query yet.  But only until it is enumerated (e.g. `ToList()` calls the `List<>` constructor which will use the `IQueryable` object's `GetEnumerator()` to fill the container), will it actually call the data source and execute the SQL query.

Comment: As is stated right in your own quote, all `IQueryable` objects *are enumerable objects*.  It is when you enumerate the query that the query is executed, not when you call a method that returns an enumerable object.

Comment: You are right.  I learned myself by reading first what I quote.  Corrected my answer.